# Как удалить полностью доп компоненты Vscode Go расширения

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-studio-extensions

Понаустанавливал разных доп расширений для Golang, кроме основного мне в маленьких окошках предложило ещё всякие vet, golint и прочее установить, ещё какая-то experimental версия Go которая работает реально намного быстрее, но работает очень, очень некорректно, куча ошибок, куча проблем.

Я эту всю бурду установил и в итоге получил непонятно что, непонятно как работающее... Просто удалить Go расширение не помогает, переустановка Vscode не помогает. Скажите что делать, потому что в таком окружении работать нереально. Может есть пути где эти всё лежит чтобы зачистить под ноль.

Comment: Удаляйте каталог расширений после удаления  vscode

Answer (score 1):

Удалите каталог расширений после удаления vscode

В зависимости от платформы:

```
Windows %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions
Mac $HOME/.vscode/extensions
Linux $HOME/.vscode/extensions
```